# Await Task.WhenAll() inside task not awaiting

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

My problem is that when a Task has a Task.WhenAll() call (running other Tasks) the line of WhenAll() makes the consuming code continue execution, unlike what I would expect. So the following code outputs "finished" immediately when the Task.WhenAll() is hit, not after all the tasks in its argument are finished.

```
    // Just a simple async method
    public Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                // Working
            });
    }

    // This one used the previous one with Task.WhenAll()
    public Task DoLoadsOfWorkAsync()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(
            async () =>
            {
                // Working
                // This line makes the task return immediately
                await Task.WhenAll(DoWorkAsync(), DoWorkAsync());
                // Working
            });
    }

    // Consuming code
    await DoLoadsOfWorkAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("finished");
```

I'd expect the WriteLine() to be called when the last line of DoLoadsOfWorkAsync() is executed.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall.aspx) returns a new [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) immediately, it does not block. The returned task will complete when all tasks passed to `WhenAll` have completed.

It is an asynchronous equivalent to [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall.aspx), and this is the method to use if you want to block.

However you have another problem. Using [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew.aspx) and passing an `async` delegate seems to lead to a type of `Task<Task>` where the outer task completes when the inner task starts to execute (rather than when it has completed).

Using the newer [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx) avoids this.

Comment: You nailed it: the problem was the Task<Task>, I have overlooked it. BTW I don't want the thread to block, just to continue execution after the previous tasks are finished. That's why I used Task.WhenAll() instead of wait together with the aync-await construct. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: if you want to read about `Task.Run` and all its goodness (and why and how it does what it does) go here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx