# C# Task.WhenAll returning before all tasks completed?

Tags: c#, .net, task

Brand new to C#.

I am testing the validity of a list of proxy servers using the TPL.  Currently I am only using localhost + Fiddler for testing purposes.  Task.WhenAll is completing before my list of tasks have actually finished.  I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753726/task-whenall-finishing-before-tasks-have-completed) on SO but unfortunately the accepted answer is something that doesn't apply to my case, since I am not calling an async void method like the OP of that question was.

***Calling code:***

```
private async Task Foo()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var proxy = new Proxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            var test = new ProxyTest("http://example.com", "Example");
            proxy.IsValid = await proxy.TestValidityAsync(test);
            Console.WriteLine(proxy.IsValid);
        });
        tasks.Add(t);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

***Relevant classes:***

```
   public class Proxy
    {
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }

        public Proxy(string ip, int port)
        {
            //TODO Validate input.
            this.IP = ip;
            this.Port = port;
        }

        public async Task<bool> TestValidityAsync(ProxyTest test)
        {
            try
            {
                var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(test.URL);
                req.Proxy = new WebProxy(this.ToString());
                var resp = await req.GetResponseAsync();
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var respBody = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                    if (respBody.Contains(test.Validation))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.IP + ":" + this.Port;
        }

    }

public class ProxyTest
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Validation { get; set; }
    public string Invalidation { get; set; }

    public ProxyTest(string url, string validation)
    {
        this.URL = url;
        this.Validation = validation;
    }

    public ProxyTest(string url, string validation, string invalidation)
    {
        this.URL = url;
        this.Validation = validation;
        this.Invalidation = invalidation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the output that you're seeing? Testing locally, this appears to run fine, and the `Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)` is indeed executing after each task has printed its true/false

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the response.  On my end, I am having the opposite result.  The true/false results are printing after Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds), rather than before as I had intended.  Very odd it is working for you and not me...sigh.  I have a feeling this has to do with my async Lambda but am not entirely sure..

Comment: Sorry, turned out to by my mistake. I can indeed reproduce what you're seeing. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13432075/563532) (in particular, using `Task.Run` rather than `Task.Factory.StartNew`) appears to solve your issue

Comment: Unless you are forced to run on .NET 4.0, you should always use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: @Rob Yeah that solves the problem, awesome!  If you want to write that as an answer rather than a comment, I can mark it...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks man, I will follow that advice in the future.

Comment: Going to mark this as a duplicate instead, as it does appear your question is the same, and the answer solved your issue

Comment: Ok no problem, I did search on SO before posting and simply didn't find that Q/A.

Comment: No problem. Closing questions as duplicates isn't necessarily a bad thing - and don't take it personally. These posts are helpful for future debuggers, who may phrase things in a similar way to you when searching. Rather than having answers spread out across many posts, they'll (ideally) all be consolidated into one post.